# How to use RTL rerender to test actions inside useEffects?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

Say I have a component that looks like:

```
const Example = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    someFunctionCall(arg)
  }, [prop1])

  useEffect(() => {
    ...
    someFunctionCall(arg)
  }, [prop2])

...
}
```

and I want to test that when I change `prop1` I get **ONE** new function call. The test should look something like:

```
it('when prop1 changes', () => {
  const { rerender } = render(<Example prop1='value1' prop2='value2' />)

  // Both useEffects get called on first render
  expect(someFunctionCall).toBeCalledTimes(2)

  rerender(<Example prop1='newValue' prop2='value2' />)

  // First useEffect gets called on prop1 update
  expect(someFunctionCall).toBeCalledTimes(3)

})
```

But this fails... The function is called 4 times because `rerender` does not 'just update props' the way it would in a real system, it renders the whole component from scratch with the new props. Which will call both `useEffect`s just like on the first render.

So how do I test this 'change in props' functionality with RTL?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to test? I almost never use Rerender.

Normally you would render the component and then use fireEvent to trigger some action. And than the component rerenders because some state is changed and then only the right useEffect should be called, so:

```
it('when prop1 changes', () => {
  render(<Example prop1='value1' prop2='value2' />)

  // Both useEffects get called on first render
  expect(someFunctionCall).toBeCalledTimes(2)
  
  const someButton = screen.getByText('buttonText') // button that changes the state of prop1.
  fireEvent.press(someButton) 

  // A rerender is triggered, because the state of prop 1 is changed 
  // and only the function inside the first useEffect is called
  expect(someFunctionCall).toBeCalledTimes(3)

})
```

If you cannot change the value of prop1 with a button or some other action, you might have to test the component above it. Also you could wonder if two useEffects this way are the best approach, but it is hard to say more without the actual code.

Comment: Thanks you for the response. The 'button or other action' comes from a sibling component and the 'prop1' state is managed by the component above. I like the idea of testing the component above, maybe even creating simple test helper component which renders the component and one button which handles the prop1 state.

Comment: Im unable to had the actual code, but maybe you are right about the the need for the two useEffects also. I will take a look. I do wonder if RTL could add an 'update props' function to make testing like this easier, but maybe it goes against their design principles. Thanks again!